# For which values of p does the integral converge

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

$\int_5^\infty \frac{dx}{x^pln|x|} $ For which values of $p$, does the integral converge?  Any help?

Comment: Hi welcome to Math.SE. What have you tried? Have you plugged in different values of $p$?

Comment: hi :) i tried to apply the comparison theorem.1-1/x < lnx so x/(x-1)> 1/lnx

Comment: I suggest you edit your post to include your attempts—you’re much more likely to get an answer that way!

Comment: $\ln(x)=o(x^\varepsilon)$, so study first $\int \frac {dx}{x^{p+\varepsilon}}$ then discuss the case $x^p\ln(x)$ for the critical value of $p$.

Comment: If you make the substitution $y = \ln \, x$ you should be able to see easily that the condition is $p>1$.

Comment: Thank you for the help. !! :)